# Not able to set text in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set the text in a text area using val property in jquery.
I have seen this being used in plenty of stackoverflow questions.

```
<textarea id="hazaa"></textarea>
$('#hazaa').val("hello");
```

Here is the jsFiddle - > https://jsfiddle.net/htzqqzp1/

Comment: Updated your fiddle, you forgot to add `jquery ` https://jsfiddle.net/htzqqzp1/2/

Comment: For everyone reading this (^ this is correct) they've changed where you add libraries in jsfiddle. You can add jQuery as an external resource, or by clicking the [javascript] label you can open the new menu http://i.imgur.com/1lgNVsT.png

Comment: @itsgoingdown please delete the question.

Comment: @ssube delete this question.

Comment: @BoltClock please delete this question , i apologize for posting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add JQuery library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/htzqqzp1/1/

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your entire html, this does work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#hazaa').val("hello");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="hazaa"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/htzqqzp1/) fiddle works. I had to add jQuery as an external resource to your original fiddle

```
$('#hazaa').val("hello");
console.log($('#hazaa').val());
```